# Kendo numeric text box error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).value is not a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendonumerictextbox

I'm trying to get and set kendonumerictextbox values, but I'm getting this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).value is not a function
```

This is how I'm trying to get the value:

```
var limEfect = $("#LimiteConsumoAvanceEfectivo").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();
```

and this is how I'm trying to set it:

```
var txtSaldoLimMensual = $("#SaldoLimiteMensualLocal").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
        txtSaldoLimMensual.value("@Model.SaldoLimiteMensualLocal");
```

It is supposed to work. It was working before I updated my kendo files.My old files were from version 2015 and now I have the last 2017 version. I'm not using the very latest 2018 version because it caused a lot of problems in my app.

Comment: It means jquery is not loaded, or loaded in the wrong order. But if you have upgraded kendo, it may require a newer version of jquery than you are currently using

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I have loaded the version of JQuery that this version of kendo has in its bundle by default, I mean, I'm loading all the files instaled by the Kendo MVC5 Nuget Package and in that package is included the version of JQuery  needed by kendo. I'm not loading any other JQuery file.